# MS Access Query problem?

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I am using this query:

```
SELECT D.Generic, D.Ww, D.Dd, D.Plan, c.TotalScan, D.Plan - c.TotalScan AS Balance
  FROM TableA D
       LEFT JOIN (
                  SELECT COUNT(a.Specific) AS TotalScan,
                         b.Generic, a.Dd,a.Ww  
                    FROM TableB a 
                         INNER JOIN TableC b 
                            ON a.Specific = b.Specific
                   GROUP 
                      BY b.Generic,a.Dd,a.Ww 
                   WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, a.TransactionDate, GETDATE()) = 0
                 ) c
          ON c.Generic = D.Generic 
             AND D.Ww = c.Ww 
             AND c.Dd = D.Dd
 WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, c.TransactionDate, GETDATE()) = 0;
```

to filter all records that is a insert in my sqlserver database.

Now i am having a hard time how can i do it ms access.

```
1. DATEDIFF(Day, TransactionDate, GetDate()) = 0  -- Not Work on MS Access(Which Filter all Records inserted in current Date) 
2. Cant display TotalScan from subquery
```

Example Output Date:

```
TransactionDate
3/21/2011 7:26:24 AM
3/21/2011 7:26:24 AM
3/22/2011 7:26:24 AM --
3/22/2011 7:26:28 AM --
3/22/2011 7:26:30 AM --
3/22/2011 7:26:32 AM --
3/22/2011 7:26:35 AM --
```

if my date today is 3/22/2011 5 records will be displayed.

Thanks in Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetDate()` is SQL Server specific, Access has `Now()` instead.

The DateDiff() function also exists in Access, but the parameter for the interval is different:

```
DateDiff("d", TransactionDate, Now())
```

Comment: Is it equivalent with this DATEDIFF(Day, TransactionDate, GetDate()) = 0 ? Thanks

Comment: Yes! "d" does the same as Day in T-SQL, and Now() is equivalent to GetDate().

Answer (score 1):

Equivalent of:

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, c.TransactionDate, GETDATE()) = 0

DATEDIFF("d", c.TransactionDate, Now()) = 0
```

Regards